# Is "keep depression away"?

Tags: phrases

I have a phrasal verb exercise:

> They do exercise in order to get fit and keep depression ____

I think the correct one is **away**. Is that correct? Because I'm still confusing about it: ***keep sth away from sth***, and Google gives few results about ***keep sth away*** with **sth** here means the thing you will remove it.

Comment: Yes, "away" works.  Just as a struggle to make money might be referred to as "keeping the wolf away from the door".

Comment: I think you'd actually be much more likely to encounter [*keep depression **at bay***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22keep+depression+at+bay%22) for your exact context (that's an estimated 1220 hits in Google Books, as compared to just 392 hits for [*keep depression **away***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22keep+depression+away%22)).

Comment: @FumbleFingers The problem is that exercise only allows to fill ONE word only so I think **at bay** is not allowed

Comment: @Tùng Vương: I don't know why you're asking here on ELU rather than [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but I don't think either site is really suited to suggesting answers to poorly-designed homework or exam questions. You should ask yourself whether you're trying to learn how to earn marks in meaningless exams, or whether you want to learn English *as actually used* by native speakers.